# Is there any medical downside of using a knee pillow when sleeping?

Tags: sleep, posture

Is there any medical downside of using a knee pillow when sleeping?

I have read many webpages that only state the upsides of using knee pillows when sleeping (e.g., https://www.tuck.com/best-knee-pillows/ and https://beddingpal.com/best-knee-pillow-reviews/), but I haven't seen any downside mentioned it. Is there any?